# Body of POST request from javascript application in browser using XMLHttpRequest is empty when arriving at the server

Tags: javascript, http, post, xmlhttprequest, httpserver

I have two applications: one web client and one java server. The web client sends an HTTP POST request with a JSON  body of data, and the server should receive the data and display it on the screen. The problem is that when the server reads the body of the request, there is nothing to read. What is wrong?

Edit: I realized that the problem is on the browser side (since I could send and read an HTTP POST request from some other website), but I still don't know what the problem is. Is this related to the browser running the code? When I use Chrome I get the described problem. When I use Firefox or IE the java server isn't even notified; it doesn't even run the handle method that is supposed to run when it gets an HTTP request.

It worked to read data at the server when I coded the content type as url encoded. I think it was: x-www-form-urlencoded. But I want to send data as JSON.

I use XMLHttpRequest for the web client, as you can see below.The web client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <script>
        
        function handleInput(){
            var title = "title";
            var reviewer = "reviewer";
            
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            
            var searchInfo = {
                title:title,
                reviewer:reviewer
            };

            xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8001');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(searchInfo));
            
        }
      
        </script>
    
    </body>
    </html
```

The server:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpContext;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8001), 0);
            HttpHandler handler = new MyHttpHandler();
            HttpContext context = server.createContext("/");
            context.setHandler(handler);
            server.start();
            System.out.println("Server started on port 8001");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The servers HTTP handler:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;

public class MyHttpHandler implements HttpHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = httpExchange.getRequestBody();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { br.readLine is always null!!!
            content.append(line);
            content.append("\n");
        }

        System.out.println("Content: " + content.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the backend code as well?

Comment: Ok, but I don't think that the problem is there.

Comment: thanks. find the problem but quite difficult to explain. please wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your server (java side, live in localhost:8001) and client (xhttp side, live in somewhere else) are separated. The request is considered as cross origin requests (CORs).

There are 2 types of cross origin requests - **Safe and unsafe**:

- Only the below `Content-Type` are considered as SAFE in cross site request:

  - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
  - `multipart/form-data`
  - `text/plain`

**So, `application/json;` is considered UNSAFE.**

---

For safe request, there is not much restriction on server so you can get the response back while using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

- client <=> POST request <=> Server

---

For unsafe request, there is a preflight request (a special OPTIONS action) to ask the server

- if client origin is allowed and
- what can the client do

before making the real request, in your case the POST request.

1. client <=> pre-flight (OPTIONS) request <=> Server
2. client <=> POST request <=> Server

---

So the problem is there is no handling of preflight request and the request cannot be processed by server.
To deal with it, you need to change your handler as follow:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.Headers;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;

public class MyHttpHandler implements HttpHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
        Headers headers = httpExchange.getResponseHeaders();
        System.out.println(httpExchange.getRequestMethod());
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // * means allow all origin, in production, it should be the origin you trust e.g. http://client.abc.com

        if (httpExchange.getRequestMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS")) {
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"); // allow clients to pass in content-type
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE");
            httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(204, -1);
            return;
        }

        InputStream is = httpExchange.getRequestBody();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // br.readLine is always null!!!
                content.append(line);
            content.append("\n");
        }

        System.out.println("Content: " + content.toString());

        // added response as well to complete the request
        String response = "Good" ;
        httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        os.close();
        httpExchange.close();
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="handleInput()">Click</button>
    <script>
      function handleInput() {
        var title = "title";
        var reviewer = "reviewer";

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            console.log('done')
        }

        var searchInfo = {
          title: title,
          reviewer: reviewer,
        };

        xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8001");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(searchInfo));
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

To further understanding CORs:

https://javascript.info/fetch-crossorigin

---

For your html

```
<form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" onSubmit="handleInput(event)">
...
</form>


<script>
function handleInput(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. It doesn't seem to work though; the handler on the server is not executed at all now once I copied your code. Should I alter the web clients code also in some way? Another question: is the request the browser is executing a cross-origin request in the sense that it tries to send the request to the java server, and that java server has not served the browser with its HTML page? So the java server is something else then the origin of the browser HTML page?

Comment: strange. no need to alter client code. In some sense, yes, you do not have response to client but still you should see `Content: {"title":"title","reviewer":"reviewer"}` on the server. Do you know how to set break point on java point to inspect the code?

Comment: or you can System.out.print `httpExchange.getRequestMethod()` and check if `OPTIONS` is there. just tested the code. should be okay. here is the screen cap: https://i.imgur.com/klJPIXp.png

Comment: like this image: https://i.imgur.com/Mv7Nhul.png add the system.out.print and see if there is anything print out. If you comment the whole if block and test it. you should only see OPTIONS without POST action.

Comment: It prints out OPTIONS, but there is no second POST request. So the browser only sends one request?

Comment: so your browser(client) send the request POST, but it is unsafe, so the browser will send the OPTIONS (pre-flight) request to server first, the server receive OPTIONS request and should return what the client can do (the if block). If nothing mentioned, the POST will not be sent

Comment: Can you check if the `if {}` block can be accessed. System.out.print inside the block or use debugger.

Comment: Which version of java are you using?

Comment: But I'm not telling the client what methods it can use?

Yes, it is accessed.

Comment: Java version 11.

Comment: the default allow methods are GET, POST, so should be no need to specify the method. but you can try adding `headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE");` to the if block as well. updated answer as well.

Comment: Maybe an easier solution would be to change the type to text/plain. That seems to work, and I can read it with Jackson so it's fine. But my web client only sends the request every other time when I execute the request...

Comment: yes. but you need json request so it would be better to stick with `application/json`. How do you send the request to server? like me, just put on the browser console?

Comment: I use XMLHttpRequest. The code is above in my post.

Comment: yes i know. i use XMLHttpRequest as you are as well and i place the code in the browser to test only. Is it how you test it? or you have a frontend ?

Comment: Oh, right, sorry :) I have an html page that I open in the browser. When I click on a button in a form on the page it calls a javascript function which sends the request.

Comment: Can you see the 204 no content in the network tab after clicking the button like in the image: https://i.imgur.com/7Tb2e3g.png

Comment: tried java 11 and some changes are made. updated the code. added response as well. you can try out.

Comment: No, it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/hEK1Uh5

Comment: um.. seems like no event triggered after the button is clicked

Comment: I tried your code. Still just prints out OPTIONS.

Comment: i attached my HTML as well based on yours in the answer. try it or cross-check with yours

Comment: Now it doesnt even print OPTIONS, with your html code.

Comment: quite weird, all works on my side. on the browser network tab, no request send to server?  can you check if handleInput is called by debugging or console.log something inside `handleInput()`

Comment: is it possible to upload your code on Github? need to see what's wrong

Comment: Yeah, really weird... This is the exact code im using right now: https://github.com/mansahlgren/temp

Comment: Now it works xD I didnt do anything! I added 2 alert(string). Wtf... Im using Windows 7. Maybe thats a factor.

Comment: on `<form>` use `<form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" onSubmit="handleInput(event)">` , In `handleInput()` function,  add `e` in the params and use e.preventDefault() to disallow form submission `function handleInput(e){ e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Yes, you do the trick. alert block the normal submission and it will works but the correct way to avoid default form submission, you need to use `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: The normal behaviour of form submission is: when clicking submit button, it will send to server directly (your handleInput() function is ignored).  But in your case, you want to process the data and send the request to server yourself, so need to add `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default form submission behaviour and wait for your command (the handleInput() logic) to send the request to server

Comment: Aha, okay. That works! Thank you very much! :) But where does the event object come from, and what is it?

Comment: updated the form submission code at the end of my answer to have a easy reading.
the event object comes from dom. every element has some sort of events, like click event, submit event, hover event. the event object there is the submit event object which is provided by form element